# Returning axios response through route handler

Tags: node.js, routes, axios

I have a question I have googled for a few days now but I seem to not find an answer that helps me and I hope someone knows what I am doing wrong here.

I have this route handler in my node.js backend which calls a function called postNewTicket inside of another file.

```
router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const ticketBody = `<h3>SOME HTML CODE</h3>`;

  try {
    await postNewTicket(
      req.body.orderedBy,         // customers username
      req.body.orderDate,         // today's date
      req.body.orderedByMail,     // customers email-adress
      ticketBody
    );

    res.status(200).send(res.data);    // CAUSE OF ERROR HERE ??
  } catch {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
});
```

My function postNewTicket looks like this:

```
async function postNewTicket(orderedBy, orderDate, orderedByMail, body) {
  await axios.post(
    `${URL_ENDPOINT}/tickets`,
    {
      title: `SOME TITLE`,
      group: "TEAM 2",
      owner_id: "SOME ID", 
      customer: orderedByMail,
      kategorie1: "SOME CATEGORY",
      kategorie2: "SOME CATEGORY",
      article: {
        subject: "SOME SUBJECT",
        body: body,
        type: "note",
        content_type: "text/html",
        internal: false,
      },
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    }
  );
}
```

postNewTicket calls another API, our Zammad Ticketsystem. Calling this API using Postman directly returns me a object where I can read the ticketnumber, where it was saved etc.

I want to return the response I get in postNewTicket() over my route handler to my frontend.

I assume this must be a fairly easy thing to do but I can not wrap my head around it and figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need to return axios response from **postNewTicket** function.
i did some changes in your method you can check.
i m just returning response from this method and receiving its where we are calling this method.

```
async function postNewTicket(orderedBy, orderDate, orderedByMail, body) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(
            `${URL_ENDPOINT}/tickets`,
            {
                title: `SOME TITLE`,
                group: "TEAM 2",
                owner_id: "SOME ID",
                customer: orderedByMail,
                kategorie1: "SOME CATEGORY",
                kategorie2: "SOME CATEGORY",
                article: {
                    subject: "SOME SUBJECT",
                    body: body,
                    type: "note",
                    content_type: "text/html",
                    internal: false,
                },
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                },
            }
        ).then((response) => {
            return resolve(response)
        }).catch(e => {
            return reject(e)
        });
    })
}
```

in your main router method you need to recv response like this.

```
router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
    const ticketBody = `<h3>SOME HTML CODE</h3>`;

    try {
        let response = await postNewTicket(
            req.body.orderedBy,         // customers username
            req.body.orderDate,         // today's date
            req.body.orderedByMail,     // customers email-adress
            ticketBody
        ).catch(e => { throw e });

        res.status(200).send(response.data);    // CAUSE OF ERROR HERE ??
    } catch {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
});
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Have very much thanks this works like a charm! :-)
I will read further into Promises, async & await and how excactly this is working. Still fairly new to coding so this helps a lot! :-)